# how to calculate totals using Sum, GroupBy in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Can you please help to translate this to linq c#, I tried but no success yet.

```
SELECT od.ProductID, p.productName, SUM (od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity) as total 
FROM products p 
JOIN [order Details] od ON od.ProductId = p.ProductId
GROUP BY od.ProductId, p.productName
ORDER BY productID ASC
```

I have tried this but it gives me an error :

```
var query =
    (from od in dal.Order_Details
        join p in dal.Products on od.ProductID equals p.ProductID
        group p by new {od.ProductID, p.ProductName}
        into g
        select new pintar
        {
            //  orderId = g.Key.OrderID,
            productId = g.Key.ProductID,
            productName = g.Key.ProductName,
            UnitPrice = od.UnitPrice,
            Quantity = od.Quantity,
            Discount = od.Discount,
            total = sum((g.Key.UnitPrice * g.Key.Quantity))
        }
        ).ToList();
```

Comment: Anytime you state 'it gives me an error', please be sure to describe the error details so we can help! Is it a compile error, runtime error, unhandled exception, what is the error message, stack trace, etc...

Comment: the error is because Quantity,Discount,UnitPrice ,Quantity not appear bacause is not in the group by i think but how can translate the sql above to linq ?

Comment: Remove those items from your select? They are not in the original that you are translating...

Comment: You're mixing aggregate data (sum) and elementary data (price etc.) in one result. Make up your mind.

Answer (score 1):

The query's close, it just needs tome restructuring to get it across the finish line. The primary problem is that there are mixed aggregate and column results in the `select` clause, as mentioned in comments. I think this should do it:

```
var query =
    (from od in dal.Order_Details
        join p in dal.Products on od.ProductID equals p.ProductID
        group od by new {od.ProductID, p.ProductName}
        into g
        select new pintar
        {
            productId = g.Key.ProductID,
            productName = g.Key.ProductName,
            total = g.Sum(a => a.UnitPrice * a.Quantity))
        }
        ).ToList();
```

The three things I've done here are:

1. `group od by` instead of `group p by` so that your `Sum()` aggregate can have access to the table you want
2. Removed all other columns that weren't in the SQL query, since that broadens the scope of the query translation and makes it difficult to debug
3. Added a lambda to the `Sum()` so that it executes on each row that gets passed in. (This is how you handle `Sum()` and other aggregate functions in linq to match they way you did it in SQL.)